# Convert CRC16 from C to Ruby using truncated polynomial 800516

Tags: c, ruby, crc16

I am very new to Ruby, please help.

This is a C code which I need to convert into Ruby.

Passing values [1,2,3,4,5] it gives me B059 in HEX

```
    unsigned short CalcCrc16(const unsigned char *Data,unsigned short DataLen)
    {
      unsigned short Temp;
      unsigned short Crc;
      Crc = 0;
      while (DataLen--)
      {
             Temp = (unsigned short)((*Data++) ^ (Crc >> 8));
             Temp ^= (Temp >> 4);
             Temp ^= (Temp >> 2);
             Temp ^= (Temp >> 1);
             Crc = (Crc << 8) ^ (Temp << 15) ^ (Temp << 2) ^ Temp;
      }
        return Crc; 
   }
```

This is the Ruby code I have tried:

```
class CRC16 
  def CRC16.CalculateCrc16(data) 
    crc = 0x0000 
    temp = 0x0000 
    i = 0 
    while i < data.Length 
      value = data[i] 
      temp = (value ^ (crc >> 8)) 
      temp = (temp ^ (temp >> 4)) 
      temp = (temp ^ (temp >> 2)) 
      temp = (temp ^ (temp >> 1)) 
      crc = (((crc << 8) ^ (temp << 15) ^ (temp << 2) ^ temp)) 
      i += 1 
    end 
    return crc 
  end 
end
```

Please help me to convert this code into Ruby. 
Thanks 
Deepak

Comment: What have you tried? Nobody will just do the work for you if you don't show at least what you've tried or where your specific problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there.

Here is the fix:

```
class CRC16 
  def CRC16.CalculateCrc16(data) 
    crc = 0
    temp = 0
    i = 0 
    while i < data.length    # Modified from OP version
      value = data[i] 
      temp = (value ^ (crc >> 8)) 
      temp = (temp ^ (temp >> 4)) 
      temp = (temp ^ (temp >> 2)) 
      temp = (temp ^ (temp >> 1)) 
      crc = (((crc << 8) ^ (temp << 15) ^ (temp << 2) ^ temp))
      crc &= 0xffff          # New - keep integer in "unsigned short" bit space
      i += 1 
    end 
    return crc 
  end 
end
```

I changed just two things to make it work as per the C version:

- `Length` -> `length`, a typo
- Ruby doesn't do `short`, or any other kind of restriction on integer size. You have to add it. That is what `crc &= 0xffff` is doing. Without it, bits shifted "out" of the short come back to haunt you and give a nonsense result.

In addition, I replaced `0x0000` with `0`, as it looked like an attempt to get Ruby to treat the integers as "short", which is not possible this way.

Comment: `crc &= 0xffff` makes sense to add in the C version to deal with variant `short` sizes.  (uint32_t be better.)

Comment: thank you very much...i got my answer from your solution...:)

Comment: one more query if i want to pass '12345'  in  place of [1,2,3,4,5]. To get the same o/p . can you please help me where to change in the code to get the desired result b059.

Comment: @Deepak Kumar Jha: The character `"1"` is different to the number `1`, are you sure you want this? Does your input really consist of an array of values 0 to 9? If so, a Ruby one-liner would be `"12345".chars.map { |c| c.to_i }` or more generally `numbers = str.chars.map { |c| c.to_i }` where `str` is your input string.